# How to play a symbol for a given number of times in adobe edge

Tags: adobe-edge

I have a symbol which displays 3 different images in a given time. I need to make such buttons that when clicked, one will loop the animation once, the other 3 times and the next 8 times.

I think I somehow need to send a parameter to the symbol but I could not figure out how.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple way to "send parameters to a symbol" is to set a variable to its instance.

Lets say your symbol called mySymbol is inside the stage.

Button1 clicked:

```
stage.getSymbol("mySymbol").setVariable("repeat",1);
```

Button2 clicked:

```
stage.getSymbol("mySymbol").setVariable("repeat",3);
```

Button3 clicked:

```
stage.getSymbol("mySymbol").setVariable("repeat",8);
```

Then in your symbol animation you put a trigger on the end like this one:

Animation ends trigger:

```
var repeat = sym.getVariable("repeat");
if(repeat > 0){
    sym.setVariable("repeat", repeat - 1);
    sym.play("animation_start");
}else{
    sym.stop();
}
```